# VSCode and starting a project with launch.json

Tags: node.js, include-path

I installed VScode, but when I try to debug it has giving me an error msg.

> Can not find runtime 'node' on PATH. Is 'node' installed?

I don't know what to do. I installed node js and what needed in it's instruction

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed nodejs then you can build the project. You are trying to debug so i think you have done installlation step right. If you try to run a starter project then its version maybe higher then your node. In this state you should install last version of the node.

I think your problem is that **your path is wrong**.

1. The file path that project's itself and the compiler looking for, should not contain any **invalid character, like empty ş, i, ü,** etc..
2. Your project has to read and write permission to that directories.

You should try aboves, your error may be change or if your launch.json is right then it will work out

Answer (score 0):

try to check

> run cmd => 'node --version'

if it is installed well, you can check the version.

if you cant check the version, add a environment variable

bascially node.js path is ''C:\Program Files\nodejs\'

Add the path into 'Path' of 'System variable'